# How to perform Samsung Certficate Registration in Tizen Studio?

Tags: deployment, certificate, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-studio

My Tizen project (wearable) developed in Tizen Studio 1.0 is ready to be installed on my Tizen device (Gear 2 by Samsung).

Actions taken
- the Extension SDK: Samsung Certificate Extension and Samsung Wearable Extension were installed by means of the Package Manager;
- The Certificate Profile, the  Author Certificate and a Distributor Certificate were created successfully by using the Certificate Manager.
-  "Permit to install application" was executed by selecting (right click) the device identifier in the connection explorer.

If I correctly interpret the very poor documentation available for Tizen Studio I have to complete the procedure by registering the Samsung certificate.

The question:
how can I perform the certificate registration?

The command bar doesn't include any button or option for this purpose.

Comment: Your SDK version please ?

Comment: I am using Tizen Studio 1.0. The required platform version is 2.2.1.

Comment: How did you connect your device with your IDE ? Wifi ? 
And What is your OS ?

Comment: The communication link is USB. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: How did you connect your Gear S2 with your Windows PC  through USB?

Comment: You have to connect through Wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Your Gear S2 and your Windows PC must be in same network to deploy from windows on Gear S2. You can do this by connecting both Windows PC and Gear S2 on same network by Wifi.

Follow the steps,

1. Switch on the Debugging mode in Settings > Gear info.
2. Switch off Bluetooth in Settings > Connections.
3. Switch on Wi-Fi in Settings > Connections and note the IP address.
   The device and the computer must be connected to the same Wi-Fi network
4. Launch the Remote Device Manager from
   Connection Explorer and click +.

Get the [Full Documentation from here.](https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/documentation/1_tizen_studio_windows.pdf) And check *Running Applications on a Target Device* section.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
There is no need to register the certificate after the completion of the procedure provided by the Certificate Manager.
The certification registration is performed directly by the Certificate Manager.